# reg ex to get price in string and add html tags in php

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to formulate a regular expression to find prices in a string and put html tags around. i've come up with this :

```
    $pattern = '/([1-9][0-9]*[,|.][0-9]{2})/i';
    $replace = "<p>$1</p>";

    $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

this works well so far for most cases except when something like 22,123 appears which will also be changed to

```
    <p>22,12</p>3
```

how can i make this reg ex ignore numbers with more than two decimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to the end of it:

```
$pattern = '/([1-9][0-9]*[,|.][0-9]{2})(?!\d)/i';
```

This stops a digit from appearing after the match. (All the `[0-9]`s could become `\d`s, by the way.)

[It works!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I8LB1T)

Comment: Oh, and about the `[,|.]` — if you meant `,` or `.`, it’s just `[,.]`.